# can I use localdb for development and mssql server as production?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio, localdb

I wrote a little tool that uses data from an MSSQL-Server.Now I was thinking, that it isn't the best practice to develop on the Production Server.

My idea was to use a localdb for development, would that be possible?

Can I somehow switch to the production Server connection when I deploy the tool?

Comment: You need to add your local MDF file to your production server. Of course they should be the same version (or the production server should be a later version)

Comment: Consider installing a local versions of SQLServer (there is a free version of it), having same version of you production SQLServer installation. Then you just need to change the connection string used for development and production server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a development environment, an SQL Server Express installation could be a better solution then a LocalDB.
It requires some time for installation, but you will work with a configuration a little bit closer to your production environment.

Answer (score 1):

This depends how safe you need to make it for a simple app you can use App.debug.config and App.release.config for this case.

Here is a link https://mitasoft.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/multipleappconfig/ for safe storage you can look on how to store the connection string in a safe store https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install LocalDB, but SQL Server Express would be a preferable approach. You should make sure that you do not version the app file config. Dev environments will differ from the server's config anyway and you might want to avoid letting untrusted developers know the prod database password. Just make sure you version all the other files, but do not track that one. If you do this, your deploy process should not endanger your prod config. Although, a backup of that config might be a useful asset.

Answer (score 0):

Use XML transformation and it will also help you out if you using continuous integration like Teamcity I have used below tool to view the difference within Visual Studio very useful tool

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=WillBuikMSFT.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms

Also check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx